# Как выровнять картинку по правой стороне от текста, чтобы не было изменений в переносе текста?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как выровнять картинку по правой стороне от текста, чтобы не было изменений в переносе текста?
Чтобы текст имел такой же вид, как и тот, который ниже границ картинки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как понимать "чтобы не было изменений в переносе текста", о каких изменениях речь? Или тебе отступ не нравится?

Comment: Я вставил картинку и из-за этого изменился перенос текста

Comment: А, ну тогда либо уменьшить картинку и/или маржин (предполагаю что тут используется `float`), либо вырвать картинку из потока элементов используя css-свойство `position` (в последнем случае возможно перекрытие). Если хочется ответов с версткой, добавь [repro] этой ситуации.

Comment: Спасибо! С position получилось.